# I can't get the ImageIcon to display properly

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, imageicon

Everything works except when I push run, it doesn't show the icon for the label in the JFrame. Does anyone know how to fix that?

```
public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    private final int speed=5;
    JLabel label;
    ImageIcon icon;
    public void create() {
        this.setSize(240,228);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setLayout(null);
        icon=new ImageIcon("rocket.png");
        label=new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        label.setIcon(icon);
        this.add(label);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've tried renaming the file, putting it in several different spots in the code, and even looked up a tutorial or two, but none of them helped.

Comment: as often seen on this site, do not use `ImageIcon` to **load** the images, prefer `ImageIO.read()` (`ImageIcon` is known for **not** throwing any exception if the file is not found - it just *returns* an `Image` with dimension -1 x -1 - code must check the size to recognize the missing image, otherwise nothing is shown)

Comment: `ImageIcon(String)` will look for a file (named `rocket.png` in this case) within the current working directory <- this is important as the "working directory" isn't always where the compiled code is.  So, the first thing would be to determine the working directory, you can use `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to print the current working directory.  You would then place your image file in this directory and try running the code again.

Comment: Remember, `ImageIcon` will fail silently, this is why we recommend using [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) - this will provide you with more information about why the image wasn't loaded. Also remember, the working directory can change, which is why, for read only resources, you should embed them within the application context - how this is done will depend on your build process, but essentially is a process by which the resources are bundled with the class files - you then use `Class#getResource` to obtain a reference to them

Comment: Please don't use a `null` layout. There are layout managers that you should use instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2F/uiswing/layout/visual.html. These will help you displaying everything correctly

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, use an `ImageIO.read()` instead of an `ImageIcon` as `ImageIcon` does not throw an exception and instead produces a 1x1 blank Image which makes it harder to find errors related to it. As for your error, the only possible thing that might not display your `ImageIcon` is that you've entered the wrong location. You have written `"rocket.png"` in your `ImageIcon` and not provided any location. This makes the program find the image in the same folder the code file is in. So, provide complete location of your image rather than just typing its name. So it should look like this:

```
icon = new ImageIcon("src\res\rocket.png");
```

Answer (score -2):

Change this:

```
icon=new ImageIcon("rocket.png");
```

to:

```
icon=new ImageIcon("src\\rocket.png");
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. Images should be loaded as *resources* or your app won't work as a deployable unit. '/src' has nothing to do with packaged apps
Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)